# Uncaught error: Cannot read property 'RATING-HEART' of null

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-track-player

so I was just following the react-native-track-player installation on an Expo app but when I imported the Track Player with `import TrackPlayer from "react-native-track-player"`, it returned this error
[image]

The error only appeared whenever I imported the TrackPlayer. I tried to add the `jcenter()` to the `build.gradle` file and created a development build for my app but nothing changed. So what seemed to be the problem and how should I fix it?